# Download large sets of documents from MongoDB using Meteor methods

Tags: mongodb, meteor, large-data

I am trying to export all the documents from a collection (which is about 12 MB) using a Meteor method but it is almost always crashing the app or never returning the results.

I am considering to upload the documents to S3 then sending a download link to the client, however it seems like having an unnecessary network connections and will make the process even longer.

Is there a better way to get large sets of data from server to client?

here is the example of that code, it is very simple.

```
'downloadUserActions': () => {
 if (Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), ['admin'])) {
   const userData = userActions.find({}).fetch();
   return userData
 }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you have a minimal reproducible example where the issue happens? I'm not sure that your approach is flawed fundamentally. It might be something about your app that causes the issue. If that fails, then you can always expose a good-old server route (think REST API) to download the data.

Comment: I agree with @ChristianFritz. In theory nothing is wrong with downloading via a DDP method so it might have to do with your code and you can always resort to REST if you can't get it to work with DDP.

Comment: @ChristianFritz thank you for your input, i was thinking the same thing however server goes silent and never returns the result, I also check the server if  there is a memory issue but never found one. I am also going to try using a filesystem library to stream the data, will keep this question updated.

Comment: 12MB is not big enough that it could crash your app. Do you still have `autopublish` package?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an approach, where you split the requests into multiple ones:

- get the document count
- until document count is completely fetched

  - get the current count of already fetched docs
  - fetch the next bunch of docs and skip already fetched ones

For this you need the `skip` option in the mongo query in order to skip the already fetched docs.

### Code example

```js
const limit = 250

Meteor.methods({
  // get the max amount of docs
  getCount () {
    return userActions.find().count()
  },
  // get the next block of docs
  // from: skip to: skip + limit
  // example: skip = 1000, limit = 500 is
  // from: 1000 to: 1500
  downloadUserActions (skip) {
    this.unblock()
    return userActions.find({}, { skip, limit }).fetch()
  }
})
```

Client:

```js
// wrap the Meteor.call into a promise
const asyncCall = (name, args) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Meteor.call(name, args, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      return reject(err)
    }
    return resolve(res)
  })
})

const asyncTimeout = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms)


const fetchAllDocs = async (destination) => {
  const maxDocs = await asyncCall('getCount')
  let loadedDocs = 0

  while (loadedDocs < maxDocs) {
    const docs = await asyncCall('downloadUserActions', loadedDocs)
    docs.forEach(doc => {
      // think about using upsert to fix multiple docs issues
      destination.insert(doc) 
    })

    // increase counter (skip value)
    loadedDocs = destination.find().count()

    // wait 10ms for next request, increase if server needs
    // more time
    await asyncTimeout(10)
  }
 
  return destination
}
```

Use it with a **local Mongo Collection** on the client:

```js
await fetchAllDocs(new Mongo.Collection(null))
```

After the function all docs are now stored in this local collection.

Play with the `limit` and the timeout (miliseconds) values in order to find a sweet-spot between user-experience and server-performance.

### Additional improvements

The code does not authenticate or validate requests. This is up to you!
Aölso you might think about adding a failsafe-machanism in case the `while` loop never completes due to some unintended errors.

### Further readings

- https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#DDPCommon-MethodInvocation-unblock
- https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection
- https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-find